# error in checking value for an angular observables inside an html form *ngIf="**!** currentUserNav$ | async"

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using currentUserNav$ observable in an html form after i apply **!** before the observable in html as below.

> *ngIf="**!** currentUserNav$ | async"

**this is the error i recieve :**
Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Subscribable | Promise): unknown', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Subscribable | Promise'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(obj: null): null', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
Overload 3 of 3, '(obj: Subscribable | Promise): unknown', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Subscribable | Promise'.

**the code i use in nav.component.ts :**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from './../_services/account.service';
import { user } from './../_models/user';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit 
{

 model :any ={}
 currentUserNav$ :  Observable<user>;

//injecting AccountService inside the nav component ;
  constructor(private accountService:AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //  this.getCurrentUser();
    this.currentUserNav$ = this.accountService.currentUser$;

  }
  login(){
   

    this.accountService.login(this.model).subscribe(response => {

      if (response != null){console.log(response);}
     
    }
    ,error => {

      console.log(error);});

   
  }
  logout(){
    this.accountService.logout();
    
  }

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meeting App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto " *ngIf="currentUserNav$ | async">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link "  href="#">Matches</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lists</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Messages</a>
          </li>
         
        </ul>
<div class="dropdown" *ngIf="currentUserNav$ | async" dropdown >
  <a class="dropdown-toggle text-light" dropdownToggle >Welcome,user</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
   <a class="dropdown-item" >Edit Profile</a>
   <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()" >logout</a>
  </div>

</div>
        <!-- here when i remove ! before currentUserNav$ the error is removed but with no functionality -->
        <form #loginForm="ngForm" *ngIf="! currentUserNav$ | async" class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 " (ngSubmit)= "login()" autocomplete="off">
          <input name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" class="form-control mr-sm-2  " type="text" placeholder="Username" >
          <input name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" class="form-control mr-sm-2  " type="password" placeholder="Password" >

          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Login  </button>
        </form>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: try `!(currentUserNav$ | async)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is interpreting the statement as `(!someObservable$)| async`. `!someObservable$` is a boolean indicating if someOversable$ was truthy or not, instead of the observable you want.

You need to change

```html
<div *ngIf="!someObservable$| async">
```

to

```html
<div *ngIf="!(someObservable$| async)">
```

Comment: Thanks It worked for me although on another machine the old code is working without ( )